# Is the pixel aspect ratio of a raster dataset always 1:1?

Tags: raster, standards

When we are talking about rasters, is the spatial resolution of the pixel defined in a raster dataset always fixed to a ratio of 1:1, eg, 1m x 1m ?

Comment: If you downvote please comment why so I can improve my question. Better yet there is an 'edit' option bellow you can use to correct what you think is missing. Thank you

Comment: You can have non square pixels, ie, a pixel represents say 1km by 2km and this information can be easily encoded in a header file, jpw, pgw, tfw, etc, though I don't think it is very common in practice. However, as far as I know, you can't have a pixel size that varies across a raster, if that is what you are asking. I am not the downvoter.

Comment: What is the reason for asking? Do you have a raster that you think might be like that, or do you want one? Maybe some background would help keeping downvoters away.

Comment: During capture of satellite imagery or air photos, there will be geometric distortion across an image, the removal of which is orthorectification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rasters are basically stored as matrices, so that pixels are located in a rectangular grid with rows and column coordinates. At this stage, they have no size.

For geographic data, this grid is located according to a reference system, using a transform. Most of the time, the data is resampled in order to align the grid with coordinate system. Then, you only need a simple affine transform (scale + shift) to switch from row/colum to the actual coordinates. Usually, square pixels are preferred for the sake of simplicity (faster display and analysis). However, resampling results in a loss of information, especially if the "structure" of the input and output grids are very different. Therefore, it is sometimes not recommended to resample your data on square pixels (e.g. satellite image with a low elevation angle, regular grid in lat long at high latitude that you want to convert into XY coordinates) or even to avoid multiple resampling (e.g. use the projection on the fly to visualize an image from another coordinate system). In those cases, you will not have a 1:1 ratio (and the ratio could change over the scene).

Comment: yes, In fact I was able to find some examples of raster datasets declaring themselves with a spatial pixel ratio witch was different than 1:1